# How to remove the cloned elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with removing cloned elements div. My code is like this

```
<div id="item_details">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="label_text">Name:</p></td>
            <td><input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="" id="item_name" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" /></td>
            <td><p class="label_text">Brand:</p></td>
            <td><input name="item_brand[]" type="text" value="" id="item_brand" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" /></td>
            <td><p class="label_text">Model No:</p></td>
            <td><input name="model_number[]" type="text" value="" id="model_number" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here the div with add and remove button

```
<div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="removeitem">
    <p style="margin:0px 0px 0px 600px;">
        <input type="button" name="remove_item" id="remove_item" value="Remove Item" class="cv-form-control button cv-submit">
    </p>
</div>
<br/>
<p style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <input type="button" name="add_item" id="add_item" value="Add New Item" class="cv-form-control button cv-submit">
</p>
```

and my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#add_item').click(function () {

        var button = $('#item_details').clone();
        button.find('input').val('');
        jQuery(".new_item_details").append(button);
        jQuery('#removeitem').show();

    });

    jQuery('#remove_item').click(function (e) {

        jQuery(".new_item_details:last").remove();
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Using this I'm unable to remove the cloned div properly.

Comment: Could you please explain 'unable to remove the cloned div properly.'?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the last child of the `#new_item_details` element to which you are appending the cloned elements

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#add_item').click(function () {
        var button = $('#item_details').clone();
        button.find('input').val('');
        button.removeAttr('id');//ID of an element must be uniue
        $(".new_item_details").append(button);
        $('#removeitem').show();
    });
    $('#remove_item').click(function (e) {
        $("#new_item_details > div").last().remove();
        $('#removeitem').toggle( !$("#new_item_details").is(":empty") );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_details">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="label_text">Name:</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="" id="item_name" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label_text">Brand:</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="item_brand[]" type="text" value="" id="item_brand" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="label_text">Model No:</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="model_number[]" type="text" value="" id="model_number" class="input_text" style="width: 126px;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="removeitem">
  <p style="margin:0px 0px 0px 600px;">
    <input type="button" name="remove_item" id="remove_item" value="Remove Item" class="cv-form-control button cv-submit">
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<p style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <input type="button" name="add_item" id="add_item" value="Add New Item" class="cv-form-control button cv-submit">
</p>
```

Comment: is there any other method to append the total div with out cloning when click the add button?

Comment: @user3454479 sorry... what do you mean

Comment: i mean without clone method when i click add item how to create new div with those elements.?

Answer (score 0):

slightly different approach , similar functionality. Here you can add multiple elements and can remove any one of those depending on choice.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
                 <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                                <h3 class="add_field_button"><a href="#">Add More Fields</a></h3>  



                                <label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon:</label> <input type="text"  id="no_telefon" name="no_telefon" class="required input_field" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')" required/> 
                                <label for="lokasi">Lokasi:</label> <input type="text" id="lokasi" name="lokasi" class="required input_field" required/>


                                </div>




                                </fieldset>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ var max_fields = 25; var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><label for="no_telefon">No.Telefon: <input type="text" name="no_telefon[]" id="no_telefon[]" class="required input_field"><label for="lokasi[]">Lokasi: <input type="text" name="lokasi[]" id="lokasi[]"  class="required input_field"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    });
    });


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.this one also fine

Comment: My profile haven't that much reputation for vote up..:) sorry